# Build Grails project (2.5) with jenkins

Tags: grails, jenkins, grails-plugin

I try to build my grails project with jenkins, i'm newbie on jenkins. 
first step i get my project from bitbucket, 
after i used the grail plugin to build but i have this error :

What's wrong with my configuration, it's not a jenkins user right issue as i could see in several tickets

```
[mycj] $ /var/jenkins_home/workspace/mycj/grailsw -Dgrails.work.dir=mycj cl

ean --non-interactive --plain-output
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/mycj/grailsw" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/mycj"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:846)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:384)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:395)
    at com.g2one.hudson.grails.GrailsBuilder.perform(GrailsBuilder.java:266)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 15 more
Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

[image]

Comment: if you look at the very end you will see `error=13, Permission denied` as suggested by npokharel

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Jenkins user doesn't have write permission on the working directory.